# Creating 2-D matrix in php

Tags: php, matrix, 2d, associative

The thing is I have to create a 2D matrix in php where each row and column must have a key. I tried to do this but what happens is that a 2-D array is created which does not resemble a matrix. I used the following code:

`$x=$row['start_id'];

$y=$row['dest_id'];

$d=$row['distance'];

$this->map[$x][$y]=$d;`

Here map is the intended matrix. The intention of this code is to create an adjacency matrix and then fill the unset cells with maximum distance. $x, $y and $d in above code are derived from result of a mysql query.

Sample Output:

```
Array (
    [10010012] => Array ( 
        [10010013] => 2
        [10010016] => 8 
    )
    [10010016] => Array ( 
        [10010015] => 5 
    )
    [10010013] => Array ( 
        [10010014] => 7 
        [10010016] => 3
    )
    [10010014] => Array ( 
        [10010015] => 2 
    )
)
```

Now the problem is that I am not able to fill the empty cells
 
e.g. row key =>[10010012] and column key=>[10010015] (Not able to set value)

Any help is appreciated. If possible also mention how to traverse through such matrices.

I am a relative beginner and have tried my best to explain my problem. However if you find any shortcomings please point them out.

Edit: The matrix is not a square one.

Comment: "Not able"? What exactly is the error message or what doesn't work?

Comment: Its not an error message. I am creating a matrix using an associative array in the wrong manner. There seems to be some problem in the logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be

```
$this->map[10010012][10010015]= MAX_DISTANCE;
```

On the other hand, why do you want to set all empty/non-existing cell to MAX_DISTANCE?  You can leave the map incomplete and whenever a cell *does not exist* you assume MAX_DISTANCE as its value.

edit: simple example

```
define('MAX_DISTANCE', PHP_INT_MAX);

$map = array(
  10010012 => array ( 10010013 => 2, 10010016 => 8),
  10010016 => array ( 10010015 => 5 ),
  10010013 => array ( 10010014 => 7, 10010016 => 3),
  10010014 => array ( 10010015 => 2 )
);

function getValue(&$map, $x, $y) {
  return isset($map[$x][$y]) ? $map[$x][$y] : MAX_DISTANCE;
}

function setValue(&$map, $x, $y, $value) {
  if ( !isset($map[$x]) ) {
    $map[$x] = array($y => $value);
  }
  else {
    $map[$x][$y] = $value;
  }
}

// get an "existing" value from $map
echo getValue($map, 10010012, 10010016), "\n";
// get a "non-existing" value from $map
echo getValue($map, 10010014, 10010016), "\n";

// set a "new" value
setValue($map, 10010014, 10010016, 5);
// $map has been altered
var_dump($map[10010014]);
```

prints

```
8
2147483647
array(2) {
  [10010015]=>
  int(2)
  [10010016]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: I cant possibly manually add max_distance to every cell. It is supposed to be automatic using a foreach loop which will set max_distance whenever it finds an unset cell.

Comment: But why set MAX_DISTANCE anyway? Why not consider "not set at all equals MAX_DISTANCE" as shown in the example? The second getValue(), i.e. `getValue($map, 10010014, 10010016)` returns MAX_DISTANCE because there is no $map[10010014][10010016] (yet). Please elaborate why this isn't sufficient.

Comment: Didnt see your edit. Now I understand what you mean to say. I will try to implement your solution and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer.